# Adding bottom padding or margin to an element gives unwanted width to entire page

Tags: html, css, width, padding, margin

```
    /* GLOBAL STYLES */
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  Font-Family: 'Ovo', Serif;
  font-size: 90px;
}

h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
  Font-Family: 'Quattrocento Sans', Sans-Serif;
}

:root{
  --bg1: #E8E0D2;
  --bg2: #9B9FAE;
  --green: #5F6D45;
  --font: #F5F1F1;
}

body{
  width: 1920px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  background-color: var(--bg1);
}

.separator{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.line{
  border-top: 1px solid var(--bg2);
}

html{
  max-width: 1920px;
}


/* HEADER */
header{
  width: 1920px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 1520px;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.header-container nav{
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 32px;
}

.nav-right{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-right ul{
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#nav-link{
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-link a{
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav-right h2{
  font-size: 19px;
}



/* MAIN */
main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
}



/* HERO */
.hero{
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  /* background-color: teal; */
}

.hero-container{
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#hero-half{
  width: 100%;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.hero-left{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.hero-left .container{
  width: 79%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.name-intro h2{
  color: var(--green);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.name-intro h2{
}

.info-box{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: var(--green);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow:-20px -10px var(--bg2);
}

.slogan{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-right{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.img-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--green);
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: url('./bg texture3.jpg');
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.me-img{
  position: relative;
  right: 75px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 560px;
}

.me-img img{
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

I Use a separator to add space and a horizontal line between the different sections of my webpage so they aren't touching, but whenever I either add margin or padding to the bottom of it the entire width of the page grows a tiny bit and now there's the sidescroll option. The extra width also appears when I add bottom margin directly to the sections themselves. Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried adding max-width to the page, but it still expands.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In your body and header, try changing `width: 1920px;` to `max-width: 100%;`. Also, in "hero-left", you may want to change that to "max-width" as well. In most cases, you wouldn't want to use `width: 100%;`